# How to add Ziplib library in Clion on Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, linker-errors

**I'm trying to add ZipLip into my project using Clion on ubuntu, but I have this output:**

```
====================[ Build | TryZip | Debug ]==================================

/home/david/Snap/clion-2019.2.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build 
   /home/david/CLionProjects/TryZip/cmake-build-debug --target TryZip -- -j 2
[ 13%] Built target bzip2
[ 31%] Built target zlib
[ 83%] Built target lzma
[ 95%] Built target ZipLib
Scanning dependencies of target TryZip
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/TryZip
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lExternalLibrary/ZipLib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/TryZip.dir/build.make:102: recipe for target '../bin/TryZip' failed
make[3]: *** [../bin/TryZip] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:109: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/TryZip.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TryZip.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/TryZip.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TryZip.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:131: recipe for target 'TryZip' failed
make: *** [TryZip] Error 2
```

**This is my Cmakefile.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(TryZip)

if(BOOST_FILESYSTEM)
    include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${BOOST_LIB_DIR})
    add_definitions(-DUSE_BOOST_FILESYSTEM)
else()
    if(MSVC)
        add_definitions(-DFILESYSTEM_EXPERIMENTAL)
    endif()
endif()
if(BOOST_FILESYSTEM)
    if(UNIX)
        find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

        target_link_libraries(${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
    endif()
endif()

add_subdirectory(ExternalLibrary/ZipLib)
link_libraries(ExternalLibrary/ZipLib)
include_directories(ExternalLibrary/ZipLib)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(TryZip main.cpp ExternalLibrary/ZipLib/ZipFile.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TryZip ZipLib)
```

Can someone help me to solve this please? 
My ZipLib folder is in the same folder as my cmakefile.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `link_libraries()` appears to accept the wrong arguments in this case. The [`link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html) command takes arguments of existing CMake targets, or library names. It is also redundant with your `target_link_libraries()` call, as this *already* links `ZipLib` to `TryZip`.

Try removing the call to `link_libraries()`, as this CMake function is deprecated and its use is highly discouraged. The `include_directories()` call is similarly deprecated, in favor of the target-specific command, so consider using [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) instead.

Assuming your added sub-directory `ExternalLibrary/ZipLib` contains an additional `CMakeLists.txt` file for configuring the `ZipLib` target, you should not need to add the `ZipFile.cpp` file again. If this file is *already* compiled in the sub-directory into the target `ZipLib`, you do not need to compile it again into `TryZip`.

```
add_subdirectory(ExternalLibrary/ZipLib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(TryZip main.cpp)

target_include_directories(TryZip PRIVATE ExternalLibrary/ZipLib)
target_link_libraries(TryZip PRIVATE ZipLib)
```

---

**EDIT**: Based on your feedback, it appears `ZipLib` also depends on `pthread` but somehow it is not getting linked correctly. You might try to add the following to your `ExternalLibrary/ZipLib/CMakeLists.txt` file (if it doesn't already exist), to utilize CMake's [FindThreads](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html) module:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

... 
target_link_libraries(ZipLib PUBLIC Threads::Threads)
```